# Find non zero solutions of a second order equation by solving for a

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been stuck on this question for the last while and looking for help:

Let a be a real constant. Consider the equation:

$y''+6y'+ay=0 $
with boundary conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y(9)=0 $

For certain discrete values of a, this equation can have non-zero solutions. Find the three smallest values of a for which this is the case.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Wheres your attempt at the problem...?

Comment: Btw, i apologize for the syntax of my equations, I'm new to this website and not quite sure how to write equations properly yet

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I assumed the only time the solutions can be non zero are if we have two complex roots and then solving for those. By solving, I know the roots must be equal to I assumed the only time the solutions can be non zero are if we have two complex roots and then solving for those. By solving, I know the roots must be equal to −3±sqrt(9−a) Im stuck after that so any help would be appreciated! – softwarechick 20 mins ago

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Non zero solutions of second order equation by solving for $a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473665/non-zero-solutions-of-second-order-equation-by-solving-for-a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roots of the characteristic equation have the form

$$ r = -3 \pm \sqrt{9-a} $$

From here you should check for 3 cases: $a = 9$, $a < 9$ and $a > 9$. The only one that gives a non-trivial solution is when $a > 9$ or $a = 9 + k^2$ and $r = -3 \pm ik$.

From here, you get the general solution

$$ y(x) = e^{-3x}\big[c_1\cos(kx) + c_2\sin(kx)\big] $$

And it's just a matter of matching boundary condition to find the appropriate constants. $y(0)=0$ gives $c_1=0$ and $y(9)=0$ gives $\sin(9k)=0$ or $k=n\pi/9$. Thus

$$ y_n(x) = e^{-3x}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{9}x\right) $$
$$ a_n = 9 + \left(\frac{n\pi}{9}\right)^2 $$